# Getting values from database and displaying in Text Views

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I am working on an android application.I want to fetch data from my database and display it in the textview. I am using Mysql server. mylay.xml is the name of my xml file which contains three textviews. In my code i am manually passing some string to the database and fetching record which matches with the string passed.

```
package com.example.festipedia_logo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;

import com.example.festipedia_logo.Searchpage.LoadAllProducts;


//import com.example.connection.disp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class calledclass extends SherlockFragment {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String[] city;
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String nameeve;
    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser  = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray products = null;
EditText b;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
//  private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.43.185:8080/festipedia/get_product_details.php";
    private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.43.185:8080/festipedia/myall.php";
Button a;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "product";


    // products JSONArray
    //JSONArray products = null;
TextView one;
TextView two;
TextView three;
String n,ll,m;
Spinner spinner;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.second);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylay, container, false);
        //  nameeve=getArguments().getString("message");
    //  setContentView(R.layout.all_products);
        one = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        two = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        three = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
//      new LoadAllProducts().execute();


        return rootView;
        // Get listview
        //ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
            }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    //@Override
        /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            //Here i am sending some name gan to the database so that it returns the details where name is gan
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eventname", "gan"));

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        //  Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    //products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
/*

                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0); */
                    JSONArray productObj = json
                            .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS); // JSON Array

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject c = productObj.getJSONObject(0);


                    /*products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(0);
                    */
                    /* n = c.getString("eventname");
                    ll = c.getString("collegename");
                     m = c.getString("location");
                */  
                    one.setText(c.getString("eventname"));
                        two.setText(c.getString("collegename"));
                        three.setText(c.getString("location"));


                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: App is crashing. @PauloBarbosa

Comment: Post your logcat. What error it has?

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA I have posted logcat.

Comment: have u checked my answer??

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA Yes,but still app is crashing.

Comment: Show me that line at where you are getting Null Pointer exception.

Comment: Sorry, But i don't know how to figure out line number from logcat. @PiYusHGuPtA

Comment: Can you please tell me the line number?

Comment: line 75 is  nameeve=getArguments().getString("message");

Comment: Must check that `message` is the same key from where you have sent it.

Comment: I removed this line as i am not using it now.

Comment: Ok so after that use my code...it will be solved.

Comment: I already made changes but still app is crashing. Logcat which i have edited is after making changes.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA Its working!But now nothing is displayed in the textviews. Can you please check my edit? Also changing  JSONParser jParser  = new JSONParser() to JSONParser jParser crashes app.

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem is that your class extends with `SherlockFragment` so you need to use `getSherlockActivity()` instead of `getActivity()`

So change from here

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

to

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getSherlockActivity());
```

and also other place at where you have used `getActivity()`.

Also just declare global variable of

```
JSONParser jParser;
```

and not initialize it on `onCreateView()` method.

```
jParser = new JSONParser();
```